# What happens when we bombard a nucleus with photons?

Tags: nuclear-physics

If we ionize an element completely and bombard it with very high energy photons e.g from synchotron radiation. What would be the result if any?

Comment: You might get some photofission. Why the need to fully ionize?

Comment: @JonCuster what about photo-production & photo-disintegration?

Answer (score 2):

Two things can happen, in the case of very energetic photons i.e., gamma rays. First, if the nucleus struck by the gamma ray photon is itself fissionable, the gamma ray can split the nucleus (photofission). Second, the gamma ray can get absorbed by the nucleus, which puts it into an excited state, after which it decays by emitting a subatomic particle (photodisintegration).

Note that gamma rays are naturally produced by processes occurring inside the nucleus and as such carry off an amount of energy typical of nuclear processes, which are of order  ~many MeV. To run such a process backwards, then, means the processes described above require similarly energetic gamma rays. Lower energy gammas will instead interact with the electron cloud surrounding the (un-ionized) nucleus, giving rise to several more possible outcomes which do not involve the nucleus at all.